# Get dynamic minor number from user space program

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I am have developed simple char driver and a simple user space application. when my driver is loaded i can access it using **/dev/xxx0** (example). So when i load my driver next time i can see the **/dev/xxx0** to **/dev/xxx1**, so i need to make change in the user program **/dev/xxx0** to **/dev/xxx1** every time when i load the driver. Is there any way from user program to get this automatically.

Comment: You could pass the path `/dev/xxx1` to your user program (as program arguments ie thru `main(int argc, char**argv)`)

Comment: Hi Kar, is your char driver an LKM?? if so then you would be creating the device file. Use the same device file in you user space application.

Comment: Not LKM. Loaded while kernel is booting.

Comment: @kar: For example I had written a linked list device driver(LKM) with device node as "/dev/list0". Find the user space application where-in I am retrieving the device file's minor number dynamically in the  link http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=4837660184730251109#allposts